# Can Excel functions recognize bold text?

Tags: html, excel, excel-formula, xlsx

For convenience sake in something work related, I need to convert text style into html format. If I have this sentence for example; "the sky is **Blue**" in a MS Word .doc document, I want to be able to copy it to excel and have the bold potion be written with html tags.

Question is, can Excel functions detect text styles? and if so which function would be correct? I was thinking of Substitute but not so sure anymore.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that will be better done in the Word before you copy it to Excel. I found this article about it (https://word.tips.net/T001904_Adding_Tags_to_Text.html) - basically just use Find and Replace where you set up the format of what are you looking for (like italic) and that you want to replace it with tags like this:

```
<i>^&</i>
```

The part ^& tells it to include the string it found, so you do not lose the content and it adds the tags before and after the string in given format.

Comment: Oh I often use ctrl + H for other purposes. Thing is I was thinking of making it automated, if I go about every bolded word and use ctrl + H to add tags it's not too different than just manually adding tags.
Thanks though. :)

Comment: You don't get me - you do not search the exact word in bold, you let the search field empty and just set up the search by the format (in bold in your case) - see the attached link, it shows everything. It finds all words in bold/italic/any other setup format and do the "replacement" (actually addition of tags in your case).

Comment: [I include picture of the setup to make it clearer ][1]

As you can see, it works by searching words based on format, not string, so you do not have to do it for each word separately. 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PiX8.jpg

Comment: Ohhhhh gotcha, I'll give it a try, thanks a lot!